# How do I alter the route defined by another module?

Tags: routes, 8

In other words, what is the Drupal 8 equivalent of [hook_menu_alter()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_menu_alter/7)?

Drupal 8 still uses `hook_menu()`, but for what I can see, the information returned by the hook is different from what the hook returned in Drupal 7. For example, the definition given in `user_menu()` for user is the following.

```
  $items['user'] = array(
    'title' => 'User account',
    'title callback' => 'user_menu_title',
    'weight' => -10,
    'route_name' => 'user_page',
    'menu_name' => 'account',
  );
```

The route_name property links to an entry in the [user.routing.yml](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core!modules!user!user.routing.yml/8) file.

```
user_page:
  pattern: '/user'
  defaults:
    _content: '\Drupal\user\Controller\UserController::userPage'
  requirements:
    _access: 'TRUE'
```

This is different from what done with Symphony, and it confuses me about how a module can alter the route defined from another user.

The only function that is still invoking `hook_menu_alter()` is `menu_router_build()`, but that function still contains code that needs to be updated, since it is still using the now deprecated `drupal_alter()`.

```
  // Alter the menu as defined in modules, keys are like user/%user.
  drupal_alter('menu', $callbacks);
  foreach ($callbacks as $path => $router_item) {
    // If the menu item is a default local task and incorrectly references a
    // route, remove it.
    // @todo This may be removed later depending on the outcome of
    // http://drupal.org/node/1889790
    if (isset($router_item['type']) && $router_item['type'] == MENU_DEFAULT_LOCAL_TASK) {
      unset($callbacks[$path]['route_name']);
    }
    // If the menu item references a route, normalize the route information
    // into the old structure. Note that routes are keyed by name, not path,
    // so the path of the route takes precedence.
    if (isset($router_item['route_name'])) {
      $router_item['page callback'] = 'USES_ROUTE';
      $router_item['access callback'] = TRUE;
      $new_path = _menu_router_translate_route($router_item['route_name']);

      unset($callbacks[$path]);
      $callbacks[$new_path] = $router_item;
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

[Allow views to override existing routing items](https://drupal.org/node/2027115#new) just uses existing functionality.

If you want to change the information attached to a route, not the menu,
like the actual used controller, or the requirements (permission/role etc.)
you can use an event provided by Drupal:

```
  <?php

  use Drupal\Core\Routing\RouteBuildEvent;
  use Drupal\Core\Routing\RoutingEvents;
  use Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\EventSubscriberInterface;

  class RouteSubscriber implements EventSubscriberInterface {
 
   /**
    * {@inheritdoc}
    */
   public static function getSubscribedEvents() {
      $events[RoutingEvents::ALTER] = 'alterRoutes';
     return $events;
   }

  /**
   * Alters existing routes.
   *
   * @param \Drupal\Core\Routing\RouteBuildEvent $event
   *   The route building event.
   */
  protected function alterRoutes(RouteBuildEvent $event) {
    // Fetch the collection which can be altered.
    $collection = $event->getRouteCollection();
    // The event is fired multiple times so ensure that the user_page route
    // is available.
    if ($route = $collection->get('user_page')) {
      // As example add a new requirement.
      $route->setRequirement('_role', 'anonymous');
    }
  }

  }
```

Additionally you have to register a service with the tag 'event_subscriber' for this class.

Comment: There are details for setting up the service registration in [Altering existing routes and adding new routes based on dynamic ones](https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/api/routing-system/altering-existing-routes-and-adding-new-routes-based-on-dynamic-ones).

Comment: The tag to use for the service is the most important part. Without that, the service would not be added to the event subscribers list, and it won't be invoked.

Comment: The code example works good, but event method (alterRoutes) should be public, instead of protected.

Answer (score 15):

Since I asked the question, Drupal 8 core code has been changed. Some of the issues about routes have been fixed.

`hook_menu()` isn't used from Drupal 8 anymore; the routes a module uses are defined in a .routing.yml file (for example [user.routing.yml](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21modules%21user%21user.routing.yml/8.9.x)). Alter hooks are still used, but since `hook_menu()` isn't invoked from Drupal core, `hook_menu_alter()` won't be invoked.

The steps necessary to alter a route defined from other modules are the following:

- Define a service tagged as *event_subscriber* (The tag is the important part, or the service would not work as expected.)

  ```yaml
  services:
    mymodule.route_subscriber:
      class: Drupal\mymodule\Routing\RouteSubscriber
      tags:
        - { name: event_subscriber }
  ```
- Create a class that extends [`RouteSubscriberBase`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Routing%21RouteSubscriberBase.php/class/RouteSubscriberBase/8.9.x)

  ```php
  namespace Drupal\mymodule\Routing;

  use Drupal\Core\Routing\RouteSubscriberBase;
  use Symfony\Component\Routing\RouteCollection;

  /**
   * Listens to the dynamic route events.
   */
  class RouteSubscriber extends RouteSubscriberBase {

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    protected function alterRoutes(RouteCollection $collection) {
      // Change the route associated with the user profile page (/user, /user/{uid}).
      if ($route = $collection->get('user.page')) {
        $route->setDefault('_controller', '\Drupal\mymodule\Controller\UserController::userPage');
      }
    }

  }
  ```

  For real implementation examples of `alterRoutes()`, see [`AdminRouteSubscriber::alterRoutes()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21modules%21system%21src%21EventSubscriber%21AdminRouteSubscriber.php/function/AdminRouteSubscriber%3A%3AalterRoutes/8.9.x) or [`RouteSubscriber::alterRoutes()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21modules%21config_translation%21src%21Routing%21RouteSubscriber.php/function/RouteSubscriber%3A%3AalterRoutes/8.9.x) .

  ```php
  protected function alterRoutes(RouteCollection $collection) {
    foreach ($collection->all() as $route) {
      if (strpos($route->getPath(), '/admin') === 0 && !$route->hasOption('_admin_route') && static::isHtmlRoute($route)) {
        $route->setOption('_admin_route', TRUE);
      }
    }
  }
  ```

  ```php
  protected function alterRoutes(RouteCollection $collection) {
    $mappers = $this->mapperManager->getMappers($collection);
    foreach ($mappers as $mapper) {
      $collection->add($mapper->getOverviewRouteName(), $mapper->getOverviewRoute());
      $collection->add($mapper->getAddRouteName(), $mapper->getAddRoute());
      $collection->add($mapper->getEditRouteName(), $mapper->getEditRoute());
      $collection->add($mapper->getDeleteRouteName(), $mapper
        ->getDeleteRoute());
    }
  }
  ```

Notice that compared with earlier Drupal 8 releases, some details are changed.

- The route name is changed from *user_page* to *user.page*
- The requirements for that route changed from `_access: 'TRUE'` to `_user_is_logged_in: 'TRUE'`
- The property to set a route controller changed from *_content* to *_controller*

Answer (score 10):

See [Altering existing routes and adding new routes based on dynamic ones](https://www.drupal.org/node/2187643); it worked nicely for me to remove /search handled by the Search module. In my case, I used the following code.

```
<?php
/**
 * @file
 * Contains \Drupal\ua_sc_module\Routing\SearchAlterRouteSubscriber.
 */

namespace Drupal\ua_sc_module\Routing;

use Drupal\Core\Routing\RouteSubscriberBase;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\RouteCollection;

/**
 * Listens to the dynamic route events.
 */
class SearchAlterRouteSubscriber extends RouteSubscriberBase {

  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  protected function alterRoutes(RouteCollection $collection) {
    // Remove the /search route.
    if ($collection->get('search.view')) {
      $collection->remove('search.view');
    }
  }

}
```