# Remove Administration Theme from user/%/edit

Tags: theming, users

I want the administration theme for all the default pages, except one: /user/%/edit

How do I get the default theme to display for this page instead of the administration theme?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

For Drupal 7 you can use [Administration theme](https://drupal.org/project/admin_theme) or [hook_admin_paths_alter()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_admin_paths_alter/7) in your custom module.

```
/**
 * Implements hook_admin_paths_alter().
 */
function my_module_admin_paths_alter(&$paths) {
  $paths['user/*/edit'] = FALSE;
}
```

For Drupal 8, see https://www.drupal.org/node/2224207.

Answer (score 1):

I believe ThemeKey allows you to control that: https://drupal.org/project/themekey

If that doesn't work,  you can force a specific theme for a page using: https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21system.api.php/function/hook_custom_theme/7

Answer (score 0):

For anyone looking for a D8 solution:

Filename: YOUR_MODULE.routing.yml

```
YOUR_MODULE.user_edit:
  path: '/user/{user}/edit'
  defaults:
    _entity_form: 'user.default'
    _title_callback: 'Drupal\user\Controller\UserController::userTitle'
  requirements:
    _entity_access: user.update
    user: \d+
  options:
    _admin_route: FALSE
```

Comment: It's better to alter the routes with route subscriber rather than defining a new one, like so: https://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/85675/14665 but setOptions needs to be used in this specific case.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback I would be interested in why it's better. If you could provide an answer with that approach, that would be amazing!

Comment: Because that's the correct way of altering existing routes. I'll provide exact solution ijn a separate answer.

Comment: Sounds good, I think my answers works well for beginner because it is super simple to implement. Looking forward to your approach altering the existing route instead of defining a new one that overrides the core route.