# Hiding /node page in Drupal 8

Tags: nodes

How can I hide the /node page in Drupal 8?

This site: https://www.drupalaid.com/blog/3-things-you-should-hide describes the reasons for hiding it and the process for Drupal 6 and 7, though no information for Drupal 8 now [hook_menu_alter()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_menu/7.x) has been removed.

Comment: Instead of hook_menu_alter(), adding a RouteSubscriber similar to @da_wehner's answer here: http://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/85675/42650. It's a bit old, but I think it's still accurate.