# Altering existing route in Drupal 8

Tags: 8, routes

I am following this tutorial: [Altering existing routes and adding new routes based on dynamic ones](https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/api/routing-system/altering-existing-routes-and-adding-new-routes-based-on-dynamic-ones) for changing the route from '/example' to '/example/helloworld'.

I tried following code in my `example` module. With `'/example'` it is working fine, but with `'/example/helloworld'` which is the new altered route it is showing `page not found`. Am I missing something in the following code? Thanks

In file: ***example.routing.yml***

```
example.content:
  path: '/example'
  defaults:
    _controller: '\Drupal\example\Controller\ExampleController::content'
    _title: 'Hello World'
  requirements:
    _permission: 'access content'
```

In file: ***example.services.yml***

```
services:
  example.route_subscriber:
    class: Drupal\example\Routing\RouteSubscriber
```

In file: ***RouteSubscriber.php***

```
class RouteSubscriber extends RouteSubscriberBase {

  public function alterRoutes(RouteCollection $collection){
    //Change path '/example' to '/example/helloworld'.
    if ($route = $collection->get('/example')){
      $route->setPath('/example/helloworld');
        }   
  } 
}
```

***File structure in module,***

[image]

Comment: This question has already been put up before.
http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/81362/how-do-i-alter-the-route-defined-by-another-module Additionally you have to register a service with the tag 'event_subscriber' for this class.

Comment: Also, the argument for `$collection->get()` is not the path, but the route name, something like _search.view_.

Comment: Thank to both for pointing out. Both point were incorporated/corrected and it is done. thanks.