# How to override controller of other modules?

Tags: 8, hooks, search

Let's say in **/var/www/drupal8/core/modules/search/src/Controller/SearchController.php**
below is the snippet

```
class SearchController extends ControllerBase {
     ...
     ...

  public function view(Request $request, SearchPageInterface $entity) {

       ...
       ...
      if (count($results)) {
         $build['search_results_title'] = array(
        '#markup' => '<h2>' . $this->t('Search results') . '</h2>',
       );
     }
      ...
   } 
}
```

So  in the above snippet I want to change the text `Search results` in line

```
'#markup' => '<h2>' . $this->t('Search results') . '</h2>',
```

I want to override above `view` method extending `class SearchController` in my custom `module`.

What are the exact steps to do this?

I am using `drupal 8.2.1`.

Comment: You'll need to alter the route [as described here](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/81362/how-do-i-alter-the-route-defined-by-another-module), probably using `$route->setDefaults()` to replace the `_controller` with your own

Comment: If you're using Search API, you could just create your own view, too.