# Add state permissions and allow state changes

Tags: 8, users, workflows, files

I'm using [Workflow](https://www.drupal.org/project/workflow) module. I want to give permission to a specific role to edit the content moderation state. I found these on permissions page but it's not working. After I update the role permission, he got "Access Denied"

Comment: Are asking how to let them moderate the content (publish/unpublish) or how to let them manage moderation states?

Comment: I mean mange moderation state

Answer (score 0):

As far as I'm aware, there's no way to give permission to manage a specific state, nor workflow for that matter.

The only permission to cover these is `administer workflows` and it covers all workflows.

You can see this by looking the `content_moderation.routing.yml`

```
content_moderation.workflow_type_edit_form:
path: '/admin/config/workflow/workflows/manage/{workflow}/type/{entity_type_id}'
defaults:
  _form: '\Drupal\content_moderation\Form\ContentModerationConfigureEntityTypesForm'
  _title_callback: '\Drupal\content_moderation\Form\ContentModerationConfigureEntityTypesForm::getTitle'
requirements:
  _permission: 'administer workflows'
```

**EDIT**
That is with the default permissions.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying. So is there any way of doing this by custom module?

Comment: Can't say I've tried, but there look to be a number of options. Access to the page you need uses `_entity_access: 'workflow.edit'`, so you could look at hook_entity_access (https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Entity%21entity.api.php/function/hook_entity_access/8.2.x), or this question: https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/81362/how-do-i-alter-the-route-defined-by-another-module

Comment: Have a look in `workflow.routing.yml` to check the appropriate routes and access controls.

Comment: Sorry, I've given `administer workflows` permission but still cannot edit the "closed" state