# Search Results page. Move the search form after the results?

Tags: 8, search

Apparently the only template file to edit is for an individual search result, located at `core/modules/search/templates/search-result.html.twig`. So you can't move the search form after the results and style accordingly?

Just want to double check this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer. If you're looking for a twig template to move around the search form, no you can't.

Long answer. Drupal core search [dynamically builds](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21modules%21search%21src%21Routing%21SearchPageRoutes.php/function/SearchPageRoutes%3A%3Aroutes/8.8.x) its search routes for all searchable entities then handles the page render via [`SearchController::view()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21modules%21search%21src%21Controller%21SearchController.php/function/SearchController%3A%3Aview/8.8.x). The controller view method only defines the theme functions/templates for the search results, not the search page as a whole.

If you wanted to move these around the render form & results elements, 
It's possible to [override the search routes via a custom module](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/81362/how-do-i-alter-the-route-defined-by-another-module) so the  `_controller` property points to a custom controller that extends `SearchController` and defines a `view()` method that does something like:

```
// in my custom search controller:
public function view(Request $request, SearchPageInterface $entity) {
  $build = parent::view($request, $entity);
  // @TODO: alter $build render array so form / results are re-ordered
  return $build;
}
```

Comment: A full example of overriding the SearchController can be found at https://stackoverflow.com/a/44522792/6046296