# View with a path of api/VERSION/foo/bar/%node - %node is not being upcast to a Node object

Tags: views, routes, 9

I am trying to create a handful of Views with a REST Export display. They have paths set behind 'api/.../.../.../%node' where %node will be an ID sent to the request to be upcasted. The basic View has a contextual filter of Content ID (excluded), and then "has any term" from this node.

However, in the contextual filter for "Taxonomy Term ID from URL" with "Load terms from the node page":

```
      if (($node = $this->routeMatch->getParameter('node')) && $node instanceof NodeInterface) {
        $entity = $node;
      }
```

This check fails, and thus the nodes terms are not checked.

Do I need a custom parameter for this purpose to tell the system what to look for? I figured as long as the ID is a node, the upcast will still occur but it is not.

Here is what xdebug sees in ViewPageController for route params and arguments:

[image]

7611 is the node ID, what part of the process should or usually would upcast this to a Node object?

If I do this in the Views TID argument, of course, then I have a Node:

```
    // Load default argument from node.
    if (!empty($this->options['node'])) {
      // Just check, if a node could be detected.
      if (($node = $this->routeMatch->getParameter('node')) && $node instanceof NodeInterface) {
        $entity = $node;
      }

      if (($node = $this->routeMatch->getParameter('node')) && !empty($node) && !($node instanceof NodeInterface)) {
        $entity = \Drupal::entityTypeManager()->getStorage('node')->load($node);
      }
    }
```

Edit: possibly related: https://www.drupal.org/project/drupal/issues/2528166

Comment: You could try to build a standard entity route with upcasting, Views recycles existing routes which should preserve the upcasting.

Comment: How would that work? I make an empty route definition, then re-use that path in Views?

Comment: Yes, I know this would only be a workaround. Otherwise there is nothing we can do here, you've already found the issue which needs to be fixed.

Comment: I see - I did not know you could do that.

Comment: @4uk4 - is that an actual feature? Is that something that might get "fixed" later?

Comment: Could you alter your view's route to tell it to upcast the parameter? https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/81362/how-do-i-alter-the-route-defined-by-another-module